# managing keep-alive http connection inside servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets

Suppose a browser makes a request
asking for the server to keep the connection alive
(connection: keep-alive).

And this request requires the invocation of a servlet.

Inside my servlet should I care to choose the best
way to send data (chunked or indicating
the lenght of the body ) ??

if the server does that for me , why , inside my servlet ,
I'm able to modyfy headers like:
content-length
and transfer encoding  ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the body length up front, you should set Content-Length header before writing body.

Otherwise do nothing; the servlet container should be able to automatically add Transfer-Encoding, and chunk-ify your body. That is subject to client/request version and Connection header.

Comment: Thanks , I have one more question,  if you could ask I would appreciate it very much: If the body of the response is small enough is it convenienet to add a content length header to prevent the server from using chunks ?

Comment: if it's easy to calculate body length. otherwise don't bother. chunk-ed encoding isn't a big deal.