# When does servlet release its thread

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, nginx

Assuming no keep alives, when a servlet container is acting as a stand alone server, I assume that the servlet's thread is not released until the entire response is sent to the client (say a web browser).  Is this a correct assumption?

But what happens if the servlet is behind a reverse proxy like Nginx?  Is the thread released once the response is delivered to Nginx, or is it held until the response is sent to its final client (say a browser)?

Update: Let me try make this a bit more clear.

It takes mere milliseconds (say 2ms) for a response to be sent from servlet to proxy like nginx.  But it can then take an additional 80ms (or so) for the final response to be sent from nginx to the browser.  Does the servlet release the thread/stream once the response is sent to nginx, or does the servlet hold onto them until the response is sent to the browser (that is the entire 80ms)

Comment: The container does not know that it is behind a proxy so this makes no difference. Usually containers use a thread pool so the threads are kept indefinitely.

Comment: But does the output of the servlet first go into a buffer/stream of nginx? At which point the servlet could think the response was fully sent, and thus the servlet closes the stream and releases the thread back to the pool.  Communication between nginx and servlet only takes a few milliseconds, while it takes (say) 80 milesconds for the final response to hit the browser.  Is the servlet holding the connection/thread the entire time, or just the time it takes to send to Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** I assume that the servlet's thread is not released until the entire response is sent to the client (say a web browser). Is this a correct assumption?

**Ans:** No it is wrong. Servlet container will just write the content to the socket and return. It is not guaranteed that return from write() method will ensure that the response has reached the client.

**Question:** Is the thread released once the response is delivered to Nginx, or is it held until the response is sent to its final client (say a browser)?

**Ans:** When Nginx is behind , then the client for Servlet container is Nginx. It is not aware of actual remote client. So, the thread will be released once the response is written to Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The server container not being able to send a response to the client will trigger an exception that will be handled by the container.  You can enclose the writing to the outputstream or writer by a try catch finally (with close()) but you don't need to, the container will manage, including the return of the thread to the pool.
Regards
S

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your answer.  Yes, it will be managed by the container, I am just wondering "when" the thread/stream is released/closed.  Particularly when it is behind something like nginx.

Comment: I've had a look at the nginx buffer config.  If the nginx's buffer is big enough to hold the entire response stream the application server will close immediately otherwise it will close when the entire stream has been flushed or a timeout occurs.  You'll have to set up a log mechanism on your application server and measure the different possibilities and respective timings.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet does not see the network. According to the [specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html) It is handled 2 objects: a Request and a Response to be filled in (in the case of HTTP, this means a HTTPRequest and a HTTPResponse). It shall process the request data within the request object, and write to the buffer in the response object. Once that content is *commited* by the servlet, the container may do some postprocessing (using filters) and will transmit it back to the client.

The servlet thread returns naturally to the pool once the call to the request handling method finishes (that may happen after the payload is sent back to the client, if the method has to do further work.

Note that because the servlet doesn't see the network and is only concerned about a single request, the state of the http connection (keep-alive or close) is independent of the servlet lifetime; several servlets may handle the different requests pipelined in a single connection. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297126/managing-keep-alive-http-connection-inside-servlet) for a related issue.